# Make ASP.NET core IHttpClientFactory throws when the requested named client is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ihttpclientfactory

I'm working with ASP.NET core 3.1 and I'm writing a web api, starting from the Visual Studio 2019 built-in ASP.NET core web api template.

One of my services has a dependency on the `IHttpClientFactory` service. I'm using the [named client consumption pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#named-clients-1). So, basically, I have code like this:

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("my-client-name");
```

I have noticed that the previous method call works even when using the name of a not existing HTTP client. By *not existing HTTP client* I mean a named HTTP client which has never been defined inside of the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

Put another way, I would expect the following code to throw, but actually it doesn't:

```
// code in Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddHttpClient("my-client-name", c =>
{
  c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "UserAgentValue");
});

// code in a custom service. I would expect this line of code to throw
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("not-existing-client");
```

Is it possible to configure an ASP.NET core 3.1 application so that the `IHttpClientFactory` has a **strict** behavior and code like the previous one throws an exception stating that the requested named client is not defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure an ASP.NET core 3.1 application so that the IHttpClientFactory has a strict behavior and code like the previous one throws an exception stating that the requested named client is not defined?

Based on the source code for [`DefaultHttpClientFactory.Create`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs,31ffde869dff2c68,references)

```
public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    HttpMessageHandler handler = CreateHandler(name);
    var client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false);

    HttpClientFactoryOptions options = _optionsMonitor.Get(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.HttpClientActions.Count; i++)
    {
        options.HttpClientActions[i](client);
    }

    return client;
}

public HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry entry = _activeHandlers.GetOrAdd(name, _entryFactory).Value;

    StartHandlerEntryTimer(entry);

    return entry.Handler;
}
```

What you describe is by design. If the client name does not exist a handler will just be added for the name used.

Comment: thanks for sharing the source. So it seems there is no way to make the factory strict, in the sense I described. I would have preferred a different behavior, so that the developer is able to spot an incorrect usage (requesting a client not explicitly configured). It seems to me a kind of silent failure.

Comment: I agree.. just wrote a unit test for this expectation and I can't make it pass since a client is returned always.  going to keep digging